# stop blink event

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

what i need is:

click in a button and make the blink event stop.

this is how i'm trying to do:

```
var blink = function(){
    $('#blinker').toggle();
};
setInterval(blink, 800);

$("#stopBlink").click(function(){
   clearInterval(blink); 
});
```

and dos not work, what i'm missing ?

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/HTRZk/20/)

Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is:

```
blink_flag = setInterval(blink, 800);

$("#stopBlink").click(function(){
   clearInterval(blink_flag); 
});
```

I'd recommend adding:

```
$('#blinker').show();
```

After the clearInterval.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `clearInterval()` in a wrong way. The parameter for the `clearInterval()` is an ID created by `setInterval()` and you are putting the function used by `setInterval()`.

```
var blink = function(){
    $('#blinker').toggle();
};
var glbTimer = setInterval(blink, 800); //declare an ID created by `setInterval()`

$("#stopBlink").click(function(){
   clearInterval(glbTimer); //clear the interval of the ID.
});
```

Check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) for more info.

Maybe you can try with this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HTRZk/21/).

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use `clearInterval` on the function. That won't work because `clearInterval` takes the interval's unique ID as a parameter. This parameter would be returned by the `setInterval` function. If you store the unique ID in a variable and pass that to `clearInterval`, it'll work fine.  Try this:

```
var blink = function(){
    $('#blinker').toggle();
};
var blinkID = setInterval(blink, 800);

$("#stopBlink").click(function(){
   clearInterval(blinkID); 
});
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HTRZk/23/)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to stop the blink toggle function, while you actually should save the interval in a variable and call clearInterval on that variable, as **clearInterval** expects an instance of the **setInterval** object as parameter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout

http://jsfiddle.net/HTRZk/22/:

```
var blink = setInterval(function(){
    $('#blinker').toggle()}
, 800);

$("#stopBlink").click(function(){
   clearInterval(blink); 
});
```

Also, you will need to make sure that when the blinking event is being stopped while the text is hidden you show the item again. Within the .click event add:

```
$('#blinker').show();
```

Comment: Oh wow, this actually adds to the discussion. The information on that specific page is correct concerning the function.

I changed the http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp link to an MDN one now though, happy?

Comment: Why does everyone take offence? I didn't say it was incorrect. You don't have a downvote, do you? I was just letting you know that W3Schools may not be the best site to be using as a reference, unless you have other options. In this case, you do have other options.

Comment: Because you might have supplied your feedback in a more constructive way. The only way to take a single link like that is offensive.

Comment: Well, sorry about that then. Didn't mean to offend you / anyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
var blink = function(){
    $('#blinker').toggle();
};
var bl = setInterval(blink, 800);

$("#stopBlink").click(function(){
   clearInterval(bl); 
});
```